# PHP - doesn`t show anything with mysqli_fetch_assoc in while-loop

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to give some data from a MySQL database to a Android App via JSON.

So far i have written this php script to give me the JSON object:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM job");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $output[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($output));
```

I have found out by accident that when I dont add the line "$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);" before the while-loop it doesn`t return anything. But when I do add this line like in the example the JSON object doesnt contain the first element.

I believe its because of this line where $row already contains the first line.

Hopefully you can help me :)

Comment: How many rows is it returing? Insert this after the query : `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);`. You **have** to remove the line `$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`.

Comment: not possible. PHP doesn't care where/how you do the fetch call. whether it's inside the while or just before it, you'll STILL be fetching a row from the db. all you're doing is throwing away that first row, unless you ALSO have `$output[] = $row;` before the `while` starts.

Comment: _when I dont add the line before the while-loop it doesn`t return anything_ Unpossible.....

Comment: what's the value of `$row` you get before the `while loop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With purpose to figure out what wrong with your query you have to do something like this:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    // Here you can see and check count of rows in your result set.
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // ...
} else {
    // Here you can see and check and understand error.
    var_export(mysqli_error($db));
}
```

with purpose to traverse all your rows from result set you have to do:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_export($row);
}
```

and you must not have `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` before while loop.